# Get latest post from facebook from iPhone?

Tags: iphone, facebook

Goal of the application is get latest post from facebook, it is possible if the user give his username and password and getting token id from facebook, using this continuously we can get and post values from facebook at a session. If the session expires we can't get the values from facebook. is there any other way to make the session alive. that is, i don't want to ask username and password from the user?

Sri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to have the user grant the "offline_access" permission which will give you a non-expiring token.

Answer (score 0):

Read out this tutorial. this tuts will help as what you want.

i go through this tuts. it wouldnot ask username and password once we logged in..

http://www.raywenderlich.com/77/how-to-post-on-facebook-with-your-iphone-app

Better he had used one bool value and usedid of the facebook using the FQLQuery.

1. Make ur session to be resume so. [_session resume];
2. When enters into FB, set your bool value and check if (![_session isConnected]) then make login otherwise, it will redirect to Posttowall.